# Finding what hour someone visits a hotel the most

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to know which hour period is the most frequent time a person visits, 2nd most frequent, 3rd most and so on. So for example 1 hour period starts at the top of the hour until the next top Eg 07:00:00-07:59:59 would be the 7am hour period.

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
id primary key
date_visited datetime not null,
cus_name varchar(32) not null
);
```

I am a little confused because I don't get how I can group by an hour

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM visits
GROUP BY date_visited
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) (particularly irritating as, plainly, you already know this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HOUR` function:

```
SELECT hour(date_visited), count(*) as number of visits
FROM visits
GROUP BY hour(date_visited)
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

If you want to give numbers to the hours according to number of visits then you can use the analytical function (MySql 8.0 or higher) as follows:

```
SELECT hour(date_visited), count(*) as number of visits,
       row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as num
FROM visits
GROUP BY hour(date_visited)
ORDER BY num
```